# Masking the folder name in the url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get my new version website online.  I have already set up and tested the 301's to direct the files from www.example.com/shop to www.example.com/test.  The only thing I now need to be able to do is make the url to show only www.example.com without the /test.  In terms of link structure I really don't want this extra folder in there.

I feel I am getting close, but have been at this for days and just can't seem to get it to work!  Can someone please help?

UPDATE!

Is it possible that software to generate SEO friendly URLs is causing a conflict?  Could this be why I am not able to achieve www.example.com rather than www.example.com/test in the URL?

EDIT

There was a conflict with the config files, which is why I couldn't get the code to work.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I have tried just about everything.  Looked through every post on here about it, and have still had no joy. This is literally the last step pf 8 months of work, can someone please help!

Comment: I feel as though ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L,NC]
should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused on what you are trying to do. Are you trying to Redirect www.example.com/shop to www.example.com/ ? If this is not what you want, please describe exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself well.  My old site /shop has 301's to redirect to the new site /test, this is working perfectly.  What I need to achieve is to hide the /test in the URL so that it displays as just www.example.com.  All of my attempts to achieve this have failed, and I either end up with the folder name not hidden, or if I can get the folder name hidden I get 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

in HTTACESS

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^something\/?$ \/something\/else\/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Is the code you sent for renaming the folder?  I.e. making it from www.example.com/test to www.example.com/shop?  I do not want to rename the folder.  What I need is that it does not display /test in the URL.

Comment: example awww.yahoo.com\/?$ www.yahoo.com all the urls will be rewritten and displayed as www.yahoo.com

Comment: would you be able to replace the something something else with things from my own example, as I do not understand what you mean.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run application located in a subfolder `test/` in the root directory, use following rewrite rules and place them in root folders `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^test/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then requests to:

```
http://www.example.com/yourscript.php
http://www.example.com/css/style.css
http://www.example.com/images/logo.png
```

Will show results from (if they don't exists in the above location):

```
http://www.example.com/test/yourscript.php
http://www.example.com/test/css/style.css
http://www.example.com/test/images/logo.png
```

Comment: I have 301's in place to redirect from shop to test - that works fine.  It is with hiding the folder name that I am having problems - one of 2 things happens, either it redirects to test but the folder name is not hidden and still displays as www.example.com/test.  OR it redirects to test, hides the folder name but can't find the pages and displays 404 errors.

Comment: @Amy so you want to help with the contents of `.htaccess` in your '/shop/' directory which will make the server use your testing version of shop in `/test/'? Is this what you want?

Comment: The 301's to redirect from /shop to /test have been set-up in .htaccess and are working perfectly.  The only issues I am having is hiding the folder name in the URL to make it display as www.example.com instead of www.example.com/test.  I have tried the above code, but instead of dispaying the pages it either keeps the URL www.example.com/test or it displays 404's.

Comment: @Amy so you want the site `www.example.com` act as it is on `www.example.com/test`? I still don't understand your websites directory structure

Comment: The old site is www.example.com/shop, it sits in the subfolder shop.  The new site www.example.com/test sits in the subfolder test, and are both under the same parent directory.  I have set-up 301's to redirect traffic from shop to test in the .htaccess, which works perfectly.  I cannot seem to hide the folder /test in the URL despite many efforts.  Is this clearer?

Comment: @Amy yes, but I doubt it's possible. What you can do is to make any subfolder (or even the parent folder) act as any other location on your website - using `mod_rewrite`. But there has to be some base URL of your application somewhere... it cannot be hidden as the browser would't know what to show... Example: you can hide `/test/ascript.php` under `/ascript.php`. The only other solution I can think of is to put the application into `iframe/frameset` - browser will then show the URL of the file with the `frameset` and the real URL of the content will be then hidden.

Comment: the example you gave is exactly what I mean, that the link index page is www.example.com rather than www.example.com/test, and the category pages become www.example.com/category instead of www.example.com/test/category

Comment: thanks for all of your help.  Turns out there was a conflict with the config files.  Got it all sorted now.