# Rewrite www.example.com to www.example.com/folder (No redirect)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite (not redirect) www.example.com to a foldername. I write:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?$ foldername
```

But the .htaccess is redirecting to www.example.com/folder, I want to keep www.example.com

Comment: Have you tried adding [PT] after the foldername?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13433876/1256403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have this rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^$ foldername [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a tailing slash; `RewriteRule ^/?$ foldername/`